# Locale settings not working after upgrading to 14.04

Tags: keyboard-layout, locale

After upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 Norwegian letters are missing from the keyboard, there is no Norwegian keyboard to select using text entry settings (only for Dvorak, Mac etc), and when I add a new user, I cannot select Norwegian as his language - it automatically slides back to English - in other words something has gone terribly wrong with locale settings.

This is the output from the command locale:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=nb_NO.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=nb_NO:fil:en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="nb_NO.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=nb_NO.UTF-8
LC_TIME=nb_NO.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="nb_NO.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=nb_NO.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="nb_NO.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=nb_NO.UTF-8
LC_NAME=nb_NO.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=nb_NO.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=nb_NO.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=nb_NO.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=nb_NO.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that the language Norwegian Bokmål is not installed. If so, please go to `System Settings -> Language Support` and install it.